# feeding a Type into a constructor

Tags: c#, types, constructor

```
class Program{ 
  void Apple(){ 
    List<Banana> apple = new List<Banana> { (new Banana(Cucumber, 5)), (new Banana(Dates, 6)) }; 
  } 
}

class Banana{
  public Banana(Type eggplant, int feijoa){     
    new eggplant(feijoa);  
  }
}

class Cucumber{
  public Cucumber(int feijoa){
  }
}

class Dates{
  public Dates(int feijoa){
  }
}
```

basically it feeds a bunch of information from the program class to the Banana class, which then filters that information and uses it to create instances of a bunch of different classes.

the problem is within the Program class, where even though it registers that a Type is needed to complete the Banana constructor, when given a Type, like Cucumber or Dates, it says giving a type there is not considered valid in the given context, so i would like some help with understanding how to fix it, thanks in advance.

while structuring my program this way might seem weird and inefficient, it's mostly to help simplify viewing and editing the front end of my program.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

you should use `typeof` operator while passing argument to constructor.

Like :

```
List<Banana> apple = new List<Banana> { (new Banana(typeof(Cucumber), 5)), (new Banana(typeof(Dates), 6)) };
```

However inside constructor you need to use `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), object[] args)` to instantiate either `Cucumber` or `Banana` objects.

**Also you better consider redesigning your class like :**

```
class Banana<T> where T: new(){
  public Banana(int feijoa){
    Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[]{feijoa}  
  }
```

so your snippet would be changed to :

```
List<Banana> apple = new List<Banana> { (new Banana<Cucumber>(5)), (new Banana<Dates>(6)) };
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the Type instance of `Cucumber` class you should use `typeof(Cucumber)`. So your constructors should change to look like the following:

```
new Banana(typeof(Cucumber), 5)
new Banana(typeof(Dates), 6)
```

**UPDATE**

Here is some more context regarding your code. The constructor of the `Banana` type is actually incorrect.

It's not possible to call `new` on a type instance. What you're actually trying to do is instantiate an object of the passed `eggplant` parameter. There are multiple ways you can achieve that. But before going into details I recommend you to [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors) about type constructors first.

Besides, it's a bit unclear what your intent is. What you're trying to do with the newly created instance. I would just assume for now that you're going to store that instance in some member variable, as follows:

```
public class Banana
{
    private readonly object instance;

    public Banana(Type eggplant, int feijoa)
    {
        this.instance = Activator.CreateInstancenew eggplant(feijoa, new object [] {feijoa});
    }
}
```

Here I've used the `Activator` type which will create an instance of a given type if it'll find a matching constructor based on the parameters you've passed. Otherwise, an exception will be thrown.

While the above-mentioned approach would work, it's not ideal as it provides no type safety. So it would be great to use Generics here, but that is not possible with current code because of the requirement of having a constructor, which accepts a parameter. There is still a way to achieve that, but it'll require a lot of code changes, which is not directly related to your question. You can read more about Generics [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/index).

While there are a lot of other options, I would ask whether it's really a requirement to have the design you've got here. Why not pass in the instances to the Banan class directly. To do that, you'll need to make sure there is a base class/interface, which all the potential parameters to the Banana constructor will extend. Here is an example you could go with:

```
class Program
{
    void Apple()
    {
        List<Banana> apple = new List<Banana> { new Banana(new Cucumber(5)), new Banana(new Dates() { Feijoa = 6 }) };
    }
}

class Banana
{
    private readonly ICommon instance;

    public Banana(ICommon instance)
    {
        this.instance = instance;
    }
}

public interface ICommon
{
    int Feijoa { get; set; }
}

class Cucumber : ICommon
{
    public Cucumber(int feijoa)
    {
        this.Feijoa = feijoa;
    }

    public int Feijoa { get; set; }
}

class Dates : ICommon
{
    public Dates()
    {
    }

    public int Feijoa { get; set; }
}
```

Sorry, the provided context is not enought to be more specific. In the meantime, I tried to share as much as possible. I know, it may look scattered a bit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This won't work with how he is instantiating the type inside the constructor. The answer is generics.

Comment: Agree. I tried to answer his specific question, though. I'll update my answer to give guidance too.